# What is wrong with my understanding of Promise in javascript that the `then` method executes functions that return Promise object, one at a time?

Tags: javascript

I try implement changing texts inside the DOM using javascript's Promise.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>js document api exercises</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const wait_thirty_sec = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('waited for 3 seconds');
                resolve('ok!!');
            }, 3000 )}
        )
        
        const insert_texts = (text) => {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {{
            document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>`+text+`</h1>`;
            console.log('inserted '+text+' into body'); 
            resolve('write doc!!!');
        }})
    };
            
        // insert contents into body  using javascript 
        wait_thirty_sec
       .then(() => insert_texts('Hello World!')) 
       .then(() => wait_thirty_sec) // this part fails to happen in the expected order
       .then(() => insert_texts('As from the hazy past ye rise to view;'))

    </script>
</html>
```

This implementation is not successful because I only can see `As from the hazy past ye rise to view;` displayed after about 3000ms.

This function `wait_thirty_sec` failed to be executed in the expected order, that is, after  `() => insert_texts('Hello World!')`, as the console output shows

```
waited for 3 seconds
inserted Hello World! into body
inserted As from the hazy past ye rise to view; into body
```

The expected output would instead be

```
inserted Hello World! into body
waited for 3 seconds
inserted As from the hazy past ye rise to view; into body
```

I was thinking that, `.then` syntax just executes functions one by one.
Now this overly simplified understanding seems to be wrong. I really wish someone can explain how Promise in javascript actually works in contrary to my interpretation.

Comment: You forgot to return promise  !

Comment: You're not calling the wait_thirty_sec func here, just returning it -> `.then(() => wait_thirty_sec)`

Comment: `.then(() => wait_thirty_sec)` just makes it wait for the *same* `wait_thirty_sec` promise again that has already been fulfilled.

Comment: "*This function `wait_thirty_sec`*" - well it is not a function, it is a promise object!

Comment: I could have realised that I had forgotten the syntax of function in javascript. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what you wanted was to first wait for seconds using the `wait_thirty_sec` function to return a promise that can be reused with asynchronous JavaScript.

**Corrected Approach:**

To ensure the correct sequence of execution, we need to utilize JavaScript promises effectively.

```
// Define a function wait_thirty_sec that returns a promise to wait for 3 seconds
const wait_thirty_sec = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("waited for 3 seconds"); // Log that 3 seconds have passed
      resolve("ok!!"); // Resolve the promise after 3 seconds
    }, 3000);
  });
};

// Define a function insert_texts that returns a promise to insert text into the body of the document
const insert_texts = (text) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    {
      document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>` + text + `</h1>`; // Insert text into the body
      console.log("inserted " + text + " into body"); // Log that text has been inserted
      resolve("write doc!!!"); // Resolve the promise after text insertion
    }
  });
};

// Call functions in sequence using promises
wait_thirty_sec() // Wait for 3 seconds
  .then(() => insert_texts("Hello World!")) // Insert "Hello World!" into body
  .then(() => wait_thirty_sec()) // Wait for another 3 seconds
  .then(() => insert_texts("As from the hazy past ye rise to view;")); // Insert another text into body
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the complete correct code! This is helpful and I understand the right syntax of returning value now